# AngularJS Google Charts -Timeline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

While using the below code to generate a timeline chart using AngularJS iam facing an issue.

Basically iam not able to find the right way to import the timeline package.
Like the import below which imports the corechart package , how do i import the timeline...

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

I tried working using

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['timeline']}]}"></script>
```

butt it didnt work.

**Controller**

```
"use strict";

/*We need to manually start angular as we need to
wait for the google charting libs to be ready*/  
google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {  
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['my-app']);
});
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});


var myApp = myApp || angular.module("my-app",["google-chart"]);

myApp.controller("IndexCtrl",function($scope){  
    $scope.data1 = {};
    $scope.data1.dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    $scope.data1.dataTable.addColumn("string","Name")
    $scope.data1.dataTable.addColumn("number","Qty")
    $scope.data1.dataTable.addRow(["Test",1]);
    $scope.data1.dataTable.addRow(["Test2",2]);
    $scope.data1.dataTable.addRow(["Test3",3]);
    $scope.data1.title="My Pie"

    $scope.data2 = {};
    $scope.data2.dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    $scope.data2.dataTable.addColumn("string","Name")
    $scope.data2.dataTable.addColumn("number","Qty")
    $scope.data2.dataTable.addRow(["Test",1]);
    $scope.data2.dataTable.addRow(["Test2",2]);
    $scope.data2.dataTable.addRow(["Test3",3]);


    $scope.data4 = {};
    $scope.data4.dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    $scope.data4.dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' })
    $scope.data4.dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' })
    $scope.data4.dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' })
    $scope.data4.dataTable.addRows([[ 'Down',      new Date(1797, 2, 3,20.20),  new Date(1797, 2, 4,21.20) ],
          [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4,20.20),  new Date(1801, 2, 4,20.20) ]]);

    $scope.data3 = {};
    $scope.data3.dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    $scope.data3.dataTable.addColumn("string","Name")
    $scope.data3.dataTable.addColumn("number","Qty")
    $scope.data3.dataTable.addRow(["Test",1]);
    $scope.data3.dataTable.addRow(["Test2",2]);
    $scope.data3.dataTable.addRow(["Test3",3]);
});
```

**HTML page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
    <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="ngGoogleCharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['timeline']}]}"></script>
         <style type="text/css">
             .bigGraph {width:500px;height:500px;float:left;}
             .mediumGraph {width:400px;height:400px;float:left;}
             .smallGraph {width:200px;height:200px;float:left;}
         </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
        <div google-chart="PieChart" ng-model="data1" class="bigGraph"></div>
        <div google-chart="BarChart" ng-model="data2" class="mediumGraph"></div>
        <div google-chart="LineChart" ng-model="data3" class="smallGraph"></div>
        <div google-chart="TimeLine" ng-model="data4" class="smallGraph"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ngGoogleCharts.js**

```
"use strict";

var googleChart = googleChart || angular.module("google-chart",[]);

googleChart.directive("googleChart",function(){  
    return{
        restrict : "A",
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attr){
            var dt = $scope[$attr.ngModel].dataTable;

            var options = {};
            if($scope[$attr.ngModel].title)
                options.title = $scope[$attr.ngModel].title;
            console.log($scope[$attr.ngModel]+' \t envirName= ', $attr.googleChart+' Ele \t '+$elem[0]);
            var googleChart = new google.visualization[$attr.googleChart]($elem[0]);
            googleChart.draw(dt,options)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the error? if you are loading google chart separately, are you facing race condition problem? If yes, have you considered document ready?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are getting the error since the value for `google-chart` directive is set to `TimeLine` and the object with such a key could not be found:

```
var googleChart = new google.visualization[$attr.googleChart]($elem[0]);
```

The class name of Timeline Google Chart is `google.visualization.Timeline`

So, the solution would be to replace the value from `TimeLine` to `Timeline`:

```
<div google-chart="Timeline" ng-model="data4" class="smallGraph"></div>
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/gGrZATAVzOTAKAEXB6P3?p=preview)

Comment: no need to include `jsapi` twice --> [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OFg5ngcMw0mu3IuEdrR7?p=preview)